# Android Facebook, can't get publish_actions

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to login to Facebook with publish_actions,

```
String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getActivity());
    mCurrentSession = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getActivity()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        mCurrentSession = session;
    }

    if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(getActivity());

        if (openRequest != null) {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

            Session.setActiveSession(mCurrentSession);
            mCurrentSession.openForPublish(openRequest);
        }
    } else {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            }
        });
    }
```

but this only gives me these permissions:

```
[public_profile, email, contact_email]
```

so further more I call `mCurrentSession.requestNewPublishPermissions` on `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Log.e("TAG", mCurrentSession.getPermissions().toString());

            if (mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                        List<String> permissions = mCurrentSession.getPermissions();
                        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                            mCurrentSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                });

}
```

but then all I get is :

```
[public_profile, email]
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Login allows people to sign in quickly to an app and enjoy a personalized, social experience.

Facebook Login provides your app access to a person's public profile, friend list, and email address. These three permissions do not require review. Instead, your app's users will choose whether they want to grant access to this information.

In order for your app to access additional elements of a person's Facebook profile (read permissions) or to publish content to Facebook on their behalf (write permissions), you will need to submit for review

**You do not need to go through Login Review if your app requests these three basic permissions:**

**public_profile,**

**user_friends**,

**email**

For More Information Visit Following link.

1.[Review Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

2.[Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login)

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue,